# Why does this LibreOffice spreadsheet display a number as "TRUE"

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I copied the problem into [this sample spreadsheet](http://filedropper.com/true)

Cells A1 and A2 should both display numbers, but one displays "TRUE" instead of a number. If I go to "clear direct formatting" on A2, it will display the correct number.

What formatting is making is show "TRUE" instead of the number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When formatting as `boolean value` is selected, LO Calc displays every value !=0 as `TRUE` while 0 is displayed as `FALSE`. Internally, the numerical value is preserved, so clearing the direct formatting will show the numbers again:

Cells with numbers and default format:

[image]

Same cells with `boolean value` formatting:

[image]

Number Format window:

[image]